# hide property inside Url.Action

Tags: .net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

below code is showing id values on the time of rendering in browsers.

Can we have any different way where we can hide id values?

My scenario is when I click anchor tag it should be open new tag and hit to `MVC` controller index method with values of id

Html Code:

```
@{
   var url = Url.Action("Index", "Home", new{id="{{id=lastLatency}}"});
       url = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(url);
 }

 <a data-ng-href="@url" target="_blank">Home</a>
```

MVC controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(invViewModel objInvViewModel) {
    int getID=objInvViewModel.id //here i am getting id
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as you shouldn't expect to be able to create something like an Android or iOS app without learning how Android/iOS works as a platform, if you want to develop web applications, you need to learn how the web works as a platform. Namely, you should spend some time familiarizing yourself with the HTTP protocol. When you click an HTML link, your browser is making a GET request to a server. In a GET request, all of the data the server needs to return a response must be part of the URL, as either the path or the query string, and the entire URL as a whole uniquely identifies a particular resource.

Given that, no, you cannot "hide" the id, because without the id, it's not the same resource. Having an understanding of the platform you endeavor to develop for, makes the answer to your question obvious, which is why it's so important that you know how the web, as a platform, works.